# create a cell array of strings matlab

Tags: string, matlab, cell

Hi I am trying to create a cell array of strings with:

```
data = ['1';'2';'3';'4';'5';'6';'7';'8';'9';'10';'11';'12';'13';'14';'15';'16';'17';'18';'19';'20';];
```

where I expecting a cell array of 25 elements. but I get:

```
length(data)

= 33
```

so obviously numbers 12,13 etc are counting as 2 bits.

My question is then how do I ensure the cell array is of length 20? also the function I am putting the cell array into has to be a cell array of strings even though I am using ints!

Comment: Strings are arrays of characters in Matlab. Joining strings like this results in one long string. Aside of that: length, size etc report size in number of elements instead of bytes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create an array of strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7100841/create-an-array-of-strings)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to do:

```
data = {'1';'2';'3';'4';'5';'6';'7';'8';'9';'10';'11';'12';'13';'14';'15';'16';'17';'18';'19';'20';};
```

Use `{}`. These will form a cell array.

Comment: Sir, you saved me from eternal misery. Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

You can use `{}` instead of `[]` to build a cell, or you can use `strsplit` to build an arbitrary length cell of strings representing numbers from 1 to `N`:

```
data = strsplit(num2str(1:N));
```

**Update:** The fastest way to do this now is with the undocumented `sprintfc` function (note the "c" at the end) which prints each element to it's own cell:

```
>> A = sprintfc('%g',1:20)
A = 
  Columns 1 through 11
    '1'    '2'    '3'    '4'    '5'    '6'    '7'    '8'    '9'    '10'    '11'
  Columns 12 through 20
    '12'    '13'    '14'    '15'    '16'    '17'    '18'    '19'    '20'
>> which sprintfc
built-in (undocumented)
```

Comment: @GuntherStruyf:  Close!  That doesn't give strings.  I think you meant `data=arrayfun(@num2str,1:N,'uni',false)`.  ;)

Comment: or `cellfun(@num2str,num2cell(1:N),'uni',false)`.  So many possibilities!

Comment: @chapjc indeed, I forgot the `num2str`, I use that a lot for quickly putting numbers in a legend. But for your second option: that would be a step too much, there is no need for the `num2cell` since `arrayfun` just takes a normal array. The `strsplit` might be nicer (short and clear) actually now I look at it again